# Rails Gem Geocoder does not obey per request language setting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-geocoder

I am trying to get a different language version of an address from Geocoder using Google API. I have tried to geocode the result using the following:

```
Geocoder.search("Effel Tower", language: :fr)
```

or

```
Geocoder.search("Effel Tower", {language: :fr})
```

but nothing works. It would work if I change the configuration:

```
Geocoder::Configuration.locale = :fr
Geocoder.search("Effel Tower")
```

I have been searching for an answer... even to look into the code. https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/blob/master/lib/geocoder/lookups/google.rb. In the `google.rb` language parameter is handled so it should work: `:language`.

Any idea? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer. The language setting should be sent as string, not symbol. As a result:

```
Geocoder.search("Effel Tower", language: "fr")
```

will return French result. Thank you.